# How to loop through a nested web page for web scraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape data from a webpage.

https://www.industrynet.com/companies/

I plan to get the name of each individual company and location from this site. I figure I need to somehow loop through each page but I'm not sure how to do that if inside another page.

I am only slightly comfortable scraping through a single page, so any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, start with what you were able to do by scraping 1 page. Then try to loop through the process of clicking through the pages. just plan, like How would you do that? 1) Get all the links from the first page. 2) iterate through those links. 3) as you iterate, how would you grab the data you want from each of those pages? 4) Store the data some way, so that as you continue to the next link in the iteration, the data is appended (and doesn't overwrite) what you grabbed from the previous page. Start simple: Start by just looping through 2 pages. Then once that works, expand/embellish it to more

Answer (score 1):

You can think of your scraping process as a tree where you go down each branch of pages. So in some rough pseudocode it would look something like this:

```
    company_details = {}
    request the landing page and parse
    for letter_href in landing_page:
        scrape the company_code URL and parse
        company_code = some_code_you_scraped
        for company_href in company_code_page:
            scrape the company page URL and parse
            append each company info to the company_details dictionary including the company_code you grabbed from the previous page.
```

Hope this helps!